# Javascript canvas: in firefox is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firefox, canvas

I have one question-bug.

In all browsers, except ff all is ok, but in firefox sometimes, especcially on images a little bit bigger that ~500kb i see that canvas `toDataUrl` return me empty data, but base64 image is normall (e.targer.result) is not empty:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = e.target.result;
  var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  mainCanvas.width = img.width;
  mainCanvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
  scope.imagecontent = mainCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 100);
  if (!scope.$$phase) {
    scope.$apply();
  }
};
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

why it is so? what i do wrong? how to solve it? How to get non-empty canvas data from canvas? (also i use angular)

Comment: FF still has some issues with canvas.Try it using setTimeout(function(){ scope.imagecontent = mainCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 100);},500);

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the image to be loaded:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   //do stuff here
}
img.src = e.target.result;
```